# Run npm command before specific cmake target

Tags: c++, node.js, qt, build, cmake

I am trying to build QT based application with CMake and everything goes well enough. I followed [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) tutorial and I can build my application. Now I want to run `npm run build` before build using `add_custom_command` it does not seems to goes as expected.

The build process fails with

```
RCC: Error in 'tray-icon/systray.qrc': Cannot find file 'html/js/app.full.js'
AUTORCC: error: process for.build/Debug/x64/tray-icon/CMakeFiles/tray-icon.dir/qrc_systray.cpp failed:
RCC: Error in 'tray-icon/systray.qrc': Cannot find file 'html/js/app.full.js'
```

Can you tell me how to execute `npm` command before the build verification step on `tray-icon/systray.qrc`?

This is my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(tray-icon)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets 5.5)
find_package(Qt5Qml 5.5)
find_package(Qt5WebEngine 5.5)
find_package(Qt5WebEngineCore 5.5)
find_package(Qt5WebEngineWidgets 5.5)

# generate rules for building source files from the resources
set(SOURCES tray-icon.cpp window.cpp systray.qrc)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)
#adds target
add_executable(tray-icon ${SOURCES})

# custom build command for javascript part of the application
add_custom_command (
  TARGET "tray-icon"
  PRE_BUILD COMMAND npm run build
)

# Find the QtWidgets library
target_link_libraries(tray-icon
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::WebEngine
        Qt5::WebEngineWidgets)

install(TARGETS tray-icon DESTINATION .)
```

## PS: My final solution looks like this

```
# custom build command for javascript part of the application
add_custom_target(
  tray-icon_automoc
)
add_custom_target (
      npm-target
      COMMAND cd ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} && cd html && npm install && npm run build
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_target.html) and [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_dependencies.html#command:add_dependencies).

```
add_custom_target (
    npm-target
    COMMAND npm run build
)
add_dependencies(tray-icon npm-target)
```

To overcome the issue mentioned in the comments you should be able to add dependency using [AUTOGEN_TARGET_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/AUTOGEN_TARGET_DEPENDS.html) target property. It can be set instead to a list of dependencies for the _automoc target.

Comment: Well this seems good enough but the problem is that before `tray-icon` target there is `tray-icon_automoc` target which is automatically generated. That is the step that QT checks if the file exists. If I try to change `add_dependencies(tray-icon npm-target)` to `add_dependencies(tray-icon_automoc npm-target)` I get error that the target is undefined.

Comment: I've made it by adding custom target `tray-icon_automoc` then by changing the `add_dependencies` to depend on this target I got it to work correctly.